# A basic question regarding the proof of existence of product measure

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Suppose that $(X,\mathcal F_1,\mu)$ and $(Y,\mathcal F_2,\nu)$ are measure spaces and suppose that $\mu$ and $\nu$ are finite measures. Define the function $\nu_E : X \to \Bbb R$ by $$\nu_E(x) = \nu \big(\{y: (x,y) \in E\}\big),$$ where $E \in \mathcal F_1 \otimes \mathcal F_2$. (Note that it is not a Cartesian product, but the $\sigma-$algebra generated by the measurable rectangles). Define $$L=\{E \in \mathcal F_1 \otimes \mathcal F_2 : \nu_E \text{  is measurable}).$$ I want to prove that $L$ is a [$\lambda-$system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda-system). I am able to check the first two properties but stuck in checking that it is closed under disjoint union.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $(E_i)_{i\geq 1}\subseteq L$ is a sequence of pairwise disjoint sets from $L$ and let $E=\bigcup\limits_{i\geq 1} E_i$. Then $E\in \mathcal{F}_1\otimes \mathcal{F}_2$ and 
$$
\{y: (x,y)\in E\}=\bigcup_{i\geq 1}\,\{y:(x,y)\in E_i\}
$$
with the RHS being a pairwise disjoint union. Thus
$$
\nu_E(x)=\sum_{i\geq 1}\nu_{E_i}(x)
$$
which is measurable since each $\nu_{E_i}$ is measurable.